# Load Local Data Infile with a condition in MYSQL 5.0

Tags: mysql, load, conditional-statements, file-io

I am having a question. 
I have to upload a file into mysql 5.0 DB. 
but inside the file it has 2 kinds of information, details and header. 
it is like

H12345678900TYPE 
L12334567TYPE

and the file is not delimited, it is fixed position.

I want to load the lines which starts with H only and also has the type as TYPE.

is there anyway I can check inside the load query?

i tried `WHERE SUBSTR(@var1,1,1)='H'`

but it says the syntax error.

Any suggestion???

Thanks

Comment: Please Write full query.

Comment: Please provide table definition - SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you load file first in a temp table. and in next step import from temp table to your main table with applying condition.

Comment: I can't cos they have different columns

H12345678900TYPE this has separate sets of columns and
L12334567TYPE this has another set.

I tried separating them inside unix into 2 files, but the time taken is too long.